# Now, is AccessibilityService available on ios?

Tags: accessibilityservice

If I want to implement a third party voice over on IOS, is that possible?

I know android works, but I haven't found an ios solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.